# android debugging is working with phone but not with emulator

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm developing an android application using Intellij Idea , and when I try to debug the code using the emulator , the IDE feels like stuck at my first break point , and when I press step over button , it stays in the same line , and when I try to debug the same code while using a real android phone , it works! Does anybody know why is Intellij acting that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , I'm using Android 3 - API Level 11 in my Application , and the emulator that I used to use while debugging was using Android 4.4 - API Level 19 , after some trials I created a new emulator which uses Android 3 - API Level 11 , and now it's working fine , and I'm able to debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

the emulator can't do every thing as the quotes below says

> > All these performance problems stem from the fact that it emulates an ARM processor so it can run the actual code of your application. It
> >     accomplishes that by providing dynamic binary translation of the
> >     device machine code to the OS and processor architecture of your
> >     development machine.
>
> Basically, it does a lot of mumbo-jumbo to pretend it's an ARM
>   processor - when actually it isn't.

so it can't do to hard work like camera or some stuff i do suggest [Genymotion emulator](http://www.genymotion.com/)